# Bound for the max value of a Lagrange polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory, lagrange-interpolation

Given some Lagrange polynomial $L$(x) that interpolates over the points $x$<sub>0</sub>, $x$<sub>1</sub>,..., $x$<sub>n</sub> with values in the set  $A$ = {$a$<sub>0</sub>, $a$<sub>1</sub>,..., $a$<sub>n</sub> } on some interval [a,b], show that the max value that $L$(x) takes on the interval is bounded as such:

||$P$||<sub>∞</sub>  ≤  M||$A$||<sub>2</sub>
where M is a function of "n" (the number of interpolation points).

My Ideas:

||$P$||<sub>∞</sub> is just the magnitude of some point $P$(x<sub>i</sub>) (maybe not unique) for $P$(x) on [a,b]. So I started by representing this maximum as the linear combination of the base Lagrange polynomials:

$P$(x<sub>i</sub>) = a<sub>o</sub>q<sub>o</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) + ... + a<sub>n</sub>q<sub>n</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>)

I then squared both sides:

($P$(x<sub>i</sub>))<sup>2</sup> = (a<sub>o</sub>q<sub>o</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) + ... + a<sub>n</sub>q<sub>n</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>))<sup>2</sup>

Next, I used the Cauchy inequality to say:

($P$(x<sub>i</sub>))<sup>2</sup> = (a<sub>o</sub>q<sub>o</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) + ... + a<sub>n</sub>q<sub>n</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>))<sup>2</sup> ≤ (a<sub>o</sub><sup>2</sup> +...+ a<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>)(q<sub>o</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup> +...+ q<sub>n</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup>).

This means:

$P$(x<sub>i</sub>)) ≤ ||$A$||<sub>2</sub> (q<sub>o</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup> +...+ q<sub>n</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)<sup>1/2</sup>

But I don't know how to turn (q<sub>o</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup> +...+ q<sub>n</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)<sup>1/2</sup> = M into something that's only based on "n".

Comment: What is known about the distribution of $x_0,x_1,\ldots x_n$? Do they give a uniform partition or a Chebyshev partition?

Comment: In this video we can learn to make a kinetic analysis of a mechanical arm applying polynomial interpolation
https://youtu.be/v9p_2utyjgw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. $q_i(x)^2$ is a polinomial that equals $1$ at $x=x_i$ and has a double root at $x=x_j$ for any $j\neq i$, hence
$$ q_i(x)^2 \leq \frac{K}{K+(x-x_i)^2} \tag{1}$$
where $K$ just depends on the [mesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_an_interval#Norm_of_a_partition) $\delta$ of the partition given by $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

A continuous analogue is given by the inequality:
$$\left(\frac{\sin (\pi x)}{\pi x}\right)^2 \leq \frac{\frac{3}{\pi^2}}{\frac{3}{\pi^2}+x^2} $$
where the LHS is a function that equals $1$ at $x=0$ and has a double root at any other integer.

Now, since the function $\frac{K}{K+x^2}$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$ and its integral equals $\pi \sqrt{K}$, it is not difficult to provide a uniform bound for $\sum_{j=0}^{n}q_j(x)^2$ that depends on $n$ only.

Anyway, I am waiting to know if some extra information on the partition given by $x_0,x_1,\ldots x_n$ is available. I can give more explicit bounds for uniform or Chebyshev partitions. I am expecting that something has to be known: for instance, by taking $n=2$, $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and $x_i=\frac{5+i}{12}$ we have the following wild behaviour of $q_0(x)^2+q_1(x)^2+q_2(x)^2$:

$\hspace{1in}$[image]

At least we have to know that $x_0$ is close to $a$ and $x_n$ is close to $b$: otherwise, $(1)$ may fail, as depicted above.

Comment: How can we see that (1) holds?

Comment: @Wauzl: by estimating the LHS according to the proximity of $x$ to a root.

Comment: I don't see it yet. I'll open a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521504/estimate-for-a-lagrange-base-polynomial).