# Estimate for a Lagrange base polynomial

Tags: interpolation, estimation, lagrange-interpolation

Suppose I have a $x_0<x_1<\dots<x_n$ and a Lagrange base polynomial
$$L_i(x) = \prod_{i\neq j=0}^n \frac{x-x_j}{x_i - x_j}.$$

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1740031/42060) states, that it holds
$$ \bigl(L_i(x)\bigr)^2 \leq \frac K{K + (x-x_i)^2}$$
with a constant $K>0$.

How can I see that this holds? For which interval $I\ni x$ does it hold? How does $K$ depend on the $x_i$ and on $n$?

Comment: As pointed out before, the mesh of the partition is relevant and the inequality may fail close to the endpoints of the interpolation interval.

Comment: Since we're speaking of polynomials, the inequality can't be valid for all real $x$. So it's absolutely useless without knowing both the interval of validity, and the value of $K$.

Comment: It cannot hold for the entire interval of interpolation. It is $\bigl(L_4(0.5)\bigr)^2\approx3.8$ for $x_i = i$ ($i=0,\dots,8$), but the estimate is $\leq 1$. I think it'll hold only inside a small interval around $x_i$.